# How to add a HTML Home page to a prestashop page

Tags: html, content-management-system, prestashop-1.6

I've developed a custom HTML homepage for my prestashop site, but it seems I do not know how to incorporate it, I've tried looking into the prestashop forums, but all it shows are for .tpl files, is there a way for me to link them to the homepage?

Can I just link it as an html page or do I really need to put it inside a tpl page for it to work?

Comment: I have used a custom php page in my prestashop which works fine. I need not require to create a .tpl for that one. But it sometimes has problems in different versions of prestashop. It works for me in 1.6.0.11 . You can do the same with html page and see it it works for you. I will place the method in answer section.

Answer (score 1):

Create your .html file (say 'test.html).
In test file you need to
add these lines of code before your html code

```
<?php
 include(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
 Tools::displayFileAsDeprecated();
 include(dirname(__FILE__).'/header.php');?>
```

Also add these lines after your html code

```
<?php include(dirname(__FILE__).'/footer.php');?>
```

Place the test.html file in the public_html folder.
Now you need to add the page to link with your site.
If it is home page you need to add it to index.php otherwise you can just add the url (http://mysite/test.html) to menu bar or footer links, where ever you want to put it.
I have placed my php page link in the footer information part using anchor tag as shown in the image
[image: PHPpaymentpage]

Answer (score 0):

In prestashop you can find "Home Editorial" module, in this module you can put your html obviously the module need to be transplant in displayHome position.